# access individual fields using elastic search dsl in python

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Is the below accurate  or should it be something else ?

I am getting the expected results just checking if this is the most efficient way to access individual (nested) fields.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q

import json
client = Elasticsearch('my_server')

policy_number = 'POLICY1234'
s = Search(using=client, index = "my_index").query("term",policyNumber=policy_number.lower())
es_response = s.execute()

for hits in es_response:
   print hits['policyNumber']
   print hits.party[0]['fullName']
   print hits.party[0].partyAddress[0]['address1']
   print hits.party[0].partyAddress[0]['city']
   print hits.party[0].phoneList[0]['phoneNumber']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `execute` manually and you don't have to use `[]` to access fields by name, you can just use the attribute access:

```
for hit in s:
   print hit.policyNumber
   print hit.party[0].fullName
   print hit.party[0].partyAddress[0].address1
   print hit.party[0].partyAddress[0].city
   print hit.party[0].phoneList[0].phoneNumber
```

Comment: Good to know did not know that I could skip the execute.

If I were to not use a for loop and cared only about the 1st hit
I would have
>>> es_response = s.execute()
>>> print es_response[0].policyNumber
>>> print es_response[0].party[0].fullName
>>> print es_response[0].party[0].phoneList[0].phoneNumber

without a for loop and without calling execute() how do I do this please ?
>>> print s[0].policyNumber  does not work

Comment: That one you have to execute because slicing over the `Search` object just introduces `from`/`size` limits.